# Unable to convert strptime properly

Tags: python, django

I was trying to take a string such as '2016-07-30T20:00:00' and convert it via

```
(string, '%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S')
```

but I keep getting the error...

```
time data '2016-07-30T20:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S'
```

when I had a string such as '2016-08-08T00:00:00' it would work but I'm not sure whats causing the error for the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, you swapped between the month and the days, use:

```
(string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
#           --^--^--
```